# Why can't I cure my diseases?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have Skyrim for PlayStation 3, and in-game I have contracted 9 diseases.

Recently one of them has made my screen get considerably dark and my health drain. They don't appear in my active effects and no matter what I do, for example, drinking cure disease potions or go to a temple or shrine, they don't get cured and disappear.

I don't know what to do, and help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

You have become a [vampire](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Vampire). You can cure your vampirism by becoming a [werewolf](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Werewolf) or doing the [Rising at Dawn](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rising_at_Dawn) quest. To start the quest, ask any innkeeper for rumors as a vampire.

In the future, don't go more than 3 days while infected with [Sanguinare Vampiris](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sanguinare_Vampiris#Sanguinare_Vampiris), which you get from, big surprise, vampires.

Comment: You can also cure vampirism by become a werewolf. Being a werewolf allows you to cure diseases and still have special powers.